# RxJS can't throw an object

Tags: react-native, rxjs

I have a function to handle errors for RxJS.

```
  rxGETV(url, params) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(apiInstanceGet.get(url, params)).catch(this.handleError.bind(this))
  }

  handleError(error) {
    if (error.response) {

      if (error.response.status === 200) {
        return Rx.Observable.of(error.response)
      } else {
        console.log('2')
        console.log('error', error.response)
        return Rx.Observable.throw(error.response)
      }
    } else if (error.request) {
      console.log(error.request)
      return Rx.Observable.empty()
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      return Rx.Observable.empty()
    }
    console.log(error.config)
  }
```

I got an issue when handleError triggered into `return Rx.Observable.throw(error.response)`, it showed error `Unhandled JS Exception: [object Object]`

I wrote a dummy object to test it

```
return Rx.Observable.throw({ data:{ message: 'store not found' }, status: 404 })
```

It still shows the error `Unhandled JS Exception: [object Object]`

Is my object value wrong or something else?

Comment: What version of RxJs are you using? If it is 6 then you should be using Rx.throwError.

Comment: The version is "rxjs": "5.5.12"

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code??

```js
return Rx.Observable.throw(JSON.stringify(error.response))
```